# Automaticalli ignore error during NSIS installer and log the error message

Tags: dll, fonts, installation, nsis

I have an installer written in NSIS, and in one of it's part it tries to install some fonts, which fails:

[image]

The code part looks like this:

```
SetOverwrite ifnewer
File ".\target\fonts\*.*"

WriteRegStr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" "Arial Narrow (TrueType)" "arialn.ttf"
WriteRegStr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" "Arial Narrow Bold (TrueType)" "arialnb.ttf"
WriteRegStr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" "Arial Narrow Bold Italic (TrueType)" "arialnbi.ttf"
WriteRegStr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" "Arial Narrow Italic (TrueType)" "arialni.ttf"

GetTempFileName $R0
File /oname=$R0 ".\target\additions\fonts.dll"

Push "arialn.ttf"
CallInstDLL $R0 registerFont
Push "arialnb.ttf"
CallInstDLL $R0 registerFont     
Push "arialnbi.ttf"
CallInstDLL $R0 registerFont     
Push "arialni.ttf"
CallInstDLL $R0 registerFont
SetOverwrite on

DetailPrint "Fonts Installed"
```

This error message is not a big problem for me, so I can always ignore it.

I am wondering, how could I automatically ignore the error message popup for these font installation parts BUT log (DetailPrint) the error message?

Comment: I assume the setup runs as a elevated administrator?

Comment: of course, i run it as admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That dialog is controlled by `SetOverwrite` but there is no way to get exactly what you want out of the box.

You need to ditch the `File *` command and instead handle each file manually.

If you don't care if the new file is older then you can use `SetOverwrite try`:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!macro TryExtractWithDetailPrint file
SetOverwrite try
ClearErrors
File "${file}"
${If} ${Errors}
    DetailPrint 'Could not extract "${file}", ignoring error...'
${EndIf}
SetOverwrite lastused
!macroend

Section
SetOutPath $Fonts
!insertmacro TryExtractWithDetailPrint "c:\myfonts\font1.ttf"
!insertmacro TryExtractWithDetailPrint "c:\myfonts\font2.ttf"
SectionEnd
```

If you want to take the date stamps into account then you need to extract the new file to a temporary location and then decide if you need to try to overwrite by comparing the new and old files:

```
!macro Make64 high low result
System::Int64Op "${high}" << 32
IntFmt ${result} "%#x" "${low}" ; Must reformat as hex because we don't want negative numbers to be sign extended
System::Int64Op ${result} |
Pop ${result}
!macroend

!macro CompareFilesLastWrite oldfile newfile result
Push "${newfile}"
Push "${oldfile}"
Call CompareFilesLastWrite
Pop ${result}
!macroend
Function CompareFilesLastWrite
System::Store S
Pop $1 ; oldpath
Pop $2 ; newpath
GetFileTime $2 $R2 $R1
IntOp $R1 $R1 & 0xfc000000 ; Chop off the bottom because of FAT
GetFileTime $1 $2 $1
IntOp $1 $1 & 0xfc000000 ; Chop off the bottom because of FAT
!insertmacro Make64 $2 $1 $1 ; old
!insertmacro Make64 $R2 $R1 $2 ; new
System::Call 'KERNEL32::CompareFileTime(*lr1,*lr2)i.s'
System::Store L
FunctionEnd

!macro TryExtractIfNewer src dst
InitPluginsDir
Push $0
SetDateSave on ; Must be on for this to work
File "/oname=$PluginsDir\temp.tmp" "${src}"
!insertmacro CompareFilesLastWrite "${dst}" "$PluginsDir\temp.tmp" $0
${If} $0 < 0
    SetOverwrite try
    ClearErrors
    File "/oname=${dst}" "${src}"
    ${If} ${Errors}
        DetailPrint 'Could not extract "${dst}", ignoring error...'
    ${EndIf}
    SetOverwrite lastused
${Else}
    DetailPrint "Existing file is newer, skipping"
${EndIf}
Pop $0
!macroend

Section
!insertmacro TryExtractIfNewer "myfiles\myfont.ttf" "$fonts\myfont.ttf"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. But what if I want to try to overwrite but only if newer? So I would use something like **SetOverwrite try ifnewer** but of course it is not possible. Then how?

Comment: You would have to compare the file dates yourself in a macro.

Comment: Ah yes, you mentioned it sorry. Do you have an easy example to compare dates?

Comment: There is some date stuff on the NSIS wiki but I don't know if it is exactly what you are after.

Comment: NSIS does have a GetFileTime instruction but you need to fiddle with the numbers a bit.